# How to insert values from different cells in to a huge html string in MS EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am trying to add cell values from different fields into a cell containing a huge html string.I tried using concatenate,& methods but it says that the formula exceeds 8192 characters.I need a way to automate the html string by inserting values from other columns as I have more than 50,000 rows.I'm new to ms excel, so please be elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert material into REALLY big strings without using big formulas.  For example say **A1** contains:

```
abcd1111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

and we want to insert the word *gary* after the third character.  We start by putting *gary* in cell **A2** and then in **A3** put the formula:

```
=REPLACE(A1,3,0,A2)
```

Using **0** for the number of characters to replace makes the `REPLACE()` function behave like an `INSERT()` function:

[image]

Even though **A1** and **A2** can be REALLY big, the formula itself is quite small.